# Only show if word has certain values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Whats the best method to display only certain words that contain certain letters in an array?

For example:

If I have the words: Tree House, House, Door, Home, Full House. And I only wanted to display if each string contained the word 'house' than it would only list: Tree House, House, Full House.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have the words: Tree House, House, Door, Home, Full House." Where do you have those words? Are they separate strings? A single string? In an array? Please show your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`String#include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F) and [`String#downcase`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-downcase):

```
'Tree House'.downcase.include?('house') # => true
'Door'.downcase.include?('house') # => false
```